# SHAKE128 range calculation for MonteCarlo messages

Tags: sha-3, test-vectors

For SHAKE128 NIST has provided test vectors for Monte Carlo:

```
[Minimum Output Length (bits) = 128]
[Maximum Output Length (bits) = 1120]
Msg = c8b310cb97efa3855434998fa81c7674
COUNT = 0
Outputlen = 264
Output = fe8c476993b47b10c98303a04c6212dfb341426d748d3926140aee0a151fc80fa1
```

How they are they calculating `outputlen` for every 1000 iterations as per SHA3VS?

```
Range = (maxoutbytes – minoutbytes + 1);
Outputlen = minoutbytes + (Rightmost_Output_bits mod Range)
```

is calculated but with initial message given I get MD at `i = 0` is
`872526c9eaa7f387c5f932582ba6096b9c60fe9f16e475388d0ca350e759ac2c19`.

I convert 2c19 right most 16bits to decimal which is equal to 11289
so range = 140 -16 +1 = 125 bytes;
outputlen = 16 + (11289 mod 125) = 16 + 39 = 55 which is not equal to 264 as per the output len for count 0 given in the test vector.

Comment: The procedure referred to is [this](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media//Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/sha3/sha3vs.pdf#page=26), and the source of the data is [sha3vsha3vss](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/Secure-Hashing#sha3vsha3vss)'s [SHA-3 XOF Test Vectors for Byte-Oriented Output](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/sha3/shakebytetestvectors.zip), file SHAKE128Monte.rsp,

Comment: Yes the same procedure I am following but outputlen what NIST has given does not match with the calculated one  and I am able to get this "Output = fe8c476993b47b10c98303a04c6212dfb341426d748d3926140aee0a151fc80fa1
" value after 1000 ith iterations in the procedure

Comment: I've made some changes to the question text for readability, please verify that it still has the same content. I am not sure about the term 2c19, so maybe that needs to be changed? Hit [edit] to make any corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Outputlen = 264` in [sha3vsha3vss](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/Secure-Hashing#sha3vsha3vss)'s [SHA-3 XOF Test Vectors for Byte-Oriented Output](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/sha3/shakebytetestvectors.zip) file SHAKE128Monte.rsp (and the question's first block of data) is $\mathtt{Outputlen_0}$ of [The Secure Hash Algorithm 3 Validation System (SHA3VS)'s Figure 2](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media//Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/sha3/sha3vs.pdf#page=26) (reproduced below with whitespace tidied up). It is the width of the 1000<sup>th</sup> output of SHAKE, and computed from the 999<sup>th</sup> (which is not shown).

```
INPUT: The initial  of 128 bits long
    Initial  = (floor(/8) )*8
    // makes maxoutlen a multiple of 8 and remains within the range specified.
    {
    ₀ = ;
    for (j=0; j<100; j++) {
        for (i=1; i<1001; i++) {
            ᵢ = 128 leftmost bits of ᵢ₋₁;
            ᵢ = SHAKE(ᵢ, );
            If (i == 1000) {
                ⱼ = ;
                }
            __ = rightmost 16 bits of ᵢ;
             = ( –  + 1);
             =  + (__ mod );
            }
        ⱼ = ₁₀₀₀;
        OUTPUT: ⱼ, ⱼ
        }
    }
```

Confusingly, $\mathtt{Outputlen}$ is in bits, except in the formula computing it using $\mathtt{Range}$, which result is in bytes. This is clear in the text of [The Secure Hash Algorithm 3 Validation System (SHA3VS), page marked 23](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media//Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/sha3/sha3vs.pdf#page=27), section 3. Also, for $\mathtt{j}\in[1,99]$, the pseudocode's $\mathtt{Output_j}$ is assigned $1001$ times, with the $(j+2)^\text{th}$ assigned value shown in the output.

Said section 3 has an example of the computation of $\mathtt{Outputlen}$. I don't see any difference with what the question does, as long as it's kept in mind that the question's $55$ is a length in bytes, not bits as in file SHAKE128Monte.rsp. Since $55\times8\ne264$, the question's `872526…ac2c19` is not the correct<sup>*</sup> 999<sup>th</sup> output of SHAKE.

[This](https://github.com/earlephilhower/bearssl-esp8266/blob/b024386d461abd1b7b9be3117e2516b7541f1201/test/test_crypto.c#L1516) is an implementation of the test. All length are in bytes. $\mathtt{sref}$ is the expected 100,000<sup>th</sup> SHAKE output. It's assumed $2\le\mathtt{minoutlen}\le\mathtt{maxoutlen}\le250$. The 1001 buffers of the pseudocode are reduced to just one. If $\mathtt{minoutlen}<16$, shorter input is padded with zeroes.

Update: 8-line Python 3.8 code producing the desired output; [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBNb4MwDL3zKyymSclKESm0pFV72n29bKcOTcACpIOAIEittP/OnNB1s5RYfvZ7/uiuumpVyLt@moq@baBKh6qWGcima3sNQ5V@iQ@24k4zlB40UmVXjT69oIcD4C8G3zArcSFuzrOQBXm2jUWRhny9jsJou@VFylkeb@LIpR6wDb4ocNpRW60@VaWY1WbZX/nl3G3BnKLt4QxSzbUkojt4gLwyAej2hrIgoGAqi7GuAdW7UTuAZjD5x8a6gO5sxhjuhZ3vexKCwMKuRVhE6WnHNgn1P2UpBk3mmemdPMfIN6zTcpXs9xy@wQYsoY/33Ra301lm10ulifuuno9vL69wcD04e4Dx0Q5dC2Ux9EaWPvF/SZtB1Df3pnSafgA).

```
from hashlib import shake_128
msg, minbyt, maxbyt = bytes.fromhex("c8b310cb97efa3855434998fa81c7674"), 16, 140
outbyt, rangebyt = maxbyt, maxbyt-minbyt+1
for j in range(100):
    for i in range(1000):
        msg = shake_128((msg+bytes(14))[:16]).digest(outbyt)
        outbyt = (msg[-2]<<8 | msg[-1])%rangebyt + minbyt
    print("\nCOUNT =", j, "\nOutputlen =", len(msg)*8, "\nOutput =", msg.hex())
```

<sup>Note: the `+bytes(14)` is to handle `minbyt` below 16 bytes, down to the minimum of 2 bytes. That's not necessary for the question's parameters, but is for other SHA3VS SHAKE tests.</sup>

---

<sup>*</sup> Note: The question's erroneous bytestring `872526…ac2c19` is 264-bit wide. But 264 is supposed to be the *length derived from* the last two bytes of this bytestring, not the *length of* this bytestring. That's either a coincidence of probability 1/125, or somewhat 264 was (erroneously) an input to the process leading to this bytestring.

Comment: The Secure Hash Algorithm 3 Validation System (SHA3VS), page marked 23, 3) shows only for 2bytes of minoutlen but in the context minoutlen is 128bits which is very huge for calculation. if u see SHAKE128Monte.rsp for count1 the output length is Outputlen = 840 how did they achieve this?

Comment: In "SHAKE128Monte.rsp", `Outputlen` is the length in bits of `Output` that follows. `840` is no more than specified by `[Maximum Output Length (bits) = 1120]` and matches the 210 hex characters (105 bytes) in `Output` that follows. I don't understand why in the above comment it is stated: _minoutlen is 128bits which is very huge for calculation_.

Comment: @ 
fgrieu u mentioned previously "210 hex characters (105 bytes) in Output" how are u getting this output? can u explain with input message and MD u get.

Comment: @UmadeviPalathur: the 840 is from your first comment, and line 17 of SHAKE128Monte.rsp. It's the size in bits of the `0ed1e4…7df667` in line 18, which also is the 2000ᵗʰ output of SHAKE128 in the test. The test obtains this 840 from the last two bytes of the 1999ᵗʰ output of SHAKE128 in the test (which is `5fd0e6…24656c`), converted to integer (by big-endian convention when it comes to bytes), then reducing modulo 125 ( = 1120/8 - 128/8 + 1), then adding 16 ( = 128/8), then multiplying by 8 to get that 840 bits. Please re-read the answer, which changed a lot, then again.

Comment: I got it. I tried it before but could not trace the subsequent outputs as assignments went wrong. Thanks for your effort to make it understandable with clear pinpoints.